# Can I swap limit and expectation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I know that a random variable $X$ is integrable, that is $\mathbb{E}\left[|X| \right]<+\infty$. Can I apply the dominated convergence theorem and state that $\lim_{a \to +\infty} \mathbb{E} (|X|\ 1_{|X| \geq a})$ is equal to $\mathbb{E} \left[\lim_{a \to +\infty} |X| 1_{|X| \geq a}\right]$ and therefore equal to $0$ ?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide ! :)

Answer (score 4):

By definition a random variable $X$ is just a measurable function, hence it does not need to be integrable. Anyway, if you *assume* that $X$ is integrable, then (by DCT)
$$
\lim_n \int f_n \mathrm{d}P = \int \lim_n f_n \mathrm{d} P.
$$
whenever $f_n \le |X|$. Then, it is enough to choose $f_n=X \cdot {1}_{[n,\infty)}(|X|)$.

Comment: Thank you !! By "I know that" I meant "by assumption", indeed :) Ok, so I can swap them without problems ! Have a nice day